# The preLaunch ask 'undifined' terminated with exit code 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp8266, platformio

I'm trying to debug the following code in Visual Studio Code. I get the following error and I have no clue how to solve it. I'll be thankful for your help!

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <OLEDDisplay.h>~
#include "SSD1306.h"

void setup()
 {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.printf("Let's go! ");
   pinMode(D5,OUTPUT);

 }
void loop()
 {
  digitalWrite(D5, 0); //LED is on
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(D5,1); // LED ist off
  delay(1500); // 

}
```

This code was supposed to deliver the following results:

```
The LED is on for 0,5 sec and off for 1 sec
```

I'm trying to compile the code to see of there's any errors , and All I got is this error message:

> The preLaunchTask 'undifined' terminated with exit code 1.

Giving me the choice the `Debug anyway`, `Show Errors`, `Open Launch.json` or `cancel`. In my VS Code platformIO and the library for the microcontroller ESP8266 are installed
I've already installed `platformIO` and library for the microcontroller `ESP8266` on my VS Code.

Comment: visual studio code is saying that it's `preLauncTask: 'undefined'` failed during its run. Maybe try to compile your code with the Arduino IDE. (also the tilde after `#include <OLEDDisplay.h>~` won't help either.